# Search for the biggest amplitude in an array

Tags: java

I have a assignment to find which season has the biggest temperature amplitude. Input par is the `int` array with temperatures:

```
int T[]= {-1,-10,10,5,30,15,20,-10,30,10,29,20}
```

which means:

```
winter: -1,-10,10 spring: 5,30,15 summer: 20,-10,30 autumn: 10,29,20
```

- `temp` is always an `int`,
- `int[] T` - `T.length%4` is equal to 0 (same number of temperatures for every season, could be 2, 3 etc.)

```
{

    public String solution(int[] T){
    int length = T.length;
    int count = length/4;
    int i=0,j=0,indx=0;
    String name="";
    int maxAmpl;

    int[] winter = new int[count];
    int[] spring = new int[count];
    int[] summer = new int[count];
    int[] autumn = new int[count];
    int[] diff = new int[4];

    for(j=0,i=0;j<count; j++,i++){
        winter[i] = T[j];
    }

    for(j=count,i=0;j<count*2; j++,i++){
        spring[i] = T[j];
    }

    for(j=count*2,i=0;j<count*3; j++,i++){
        summer[i] = T[j];
    }

    for(j=count*3,i=0;j<count*4; j++,i++){
        autumn[i] = T[j];
    }

    Arrays.sort(winter);
    Arrays.sort(spring);
    Arrays.sort(summer);
    Arrays.sort(autumn);

    diff[0] = winter[count-1]-winter[0];
    diff[1] = spring[count-1]-spring[0];
    diff[2] = summer[count-1]-summer[0];
    diff[3] = autumn[count-1]-autumn[0];

    maxAmpl=diff[0];

    for(int k=1; k<4; k++){
        if (diff[k]>maxAmpl){
            maxAmpl = diff[k];
            indx = k;
        }
    }

    switch(indx){
        case 0:
            name = "WINTER";
            break;
        case 1:
            name = "SPRING";
            break;
        case 2:
            name = "SUMMER";
            break;
        case 3:
            name = "AUTUMN";
            break;
    }
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some key points:

- No need to sort the array to find min/max value
- No need to copy the array, can search in the original array using an offset `count * N`

Have a look at this:

```
public String solution(int[] T) {
    final int count = T.length / 4;
    int indx = 0;
    int last = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        int diff = IntStream.of(T).skip(count * i).limit(count).max().getAsInt()
                 - IntStream.of(T).skip(count * i).limit(count).min().getAsInt();
        if (diff > last) {
            indx = i;
            last = diff;
        }
    }
    final String[] seasons = { "WINTER", "SPRING", "SUMMER", "AUTUMN" };
    return seasons[indx];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Steps to solve this problem:

- Get slice of array related to season
- Sort slice (we could use custom `for loop` to get min and max but sorting is quite similar in performance and takes one line instead of few)
- Get first and last value from sorted slice
- Calculate amplitude and save this result in Array or List

#### Example implementation (C#):

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace application
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            var T1 = new int[] { 13, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 11, 8, 2, 10, 11, 4 };
            var T2 = new int[] { 26, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 11, 33, 2, 10, 11, 4 };
            var T3 = new int[] { 13, 2, 3, 27, 1, 6, 11, 8, 2, 10, 11, 4 };
            var T4 = new int[] { 13, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 11, 8, 2, 10, 11, 33 };

            Console.WriteLine($"Solution: {Solution(T1)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Solution: {Solution(T2)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Solution: {Solution(T3)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Solution: {Solution(T4)}");
        }

        static string Solution(int[] T)
        {
            const int numberOfSeasons = 4;
            int offset = T.Length / numberOfSeasons;
            var amplitudes = new int[numberOfSeasons];
            var seasons = new string[] { "WINTER", "SPRING", "SUMMER", "AUTUMN" };
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSeasons; i++)
            {
                var slice = new ArraySegment<int>(T, i * offset, offset).ToArray();
                Array.Sort(slice);
                var min = slice[0];
                var max = slice[slice.Length - 1];
                var amplitude = max - min;
                amplitudes[i] = amplitude;
            }
            var index = Array.IndexOf(amplitudes, amplitudes.Max());
            return seasons[index];
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```sh
Solution: WINTER
Solution: SUMMER
Solution: SPRING
Solution: AUTUMN
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].